# Why using underscores is discouraged in Julia?

Tags: julia

It is said in julia manual that 'Word separation can be indicated by underscores ('_'), but use of underscores is discouraged unless the name would be hard to read otherwise'.

I wonder why.

Comment: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/which-names-are-hard-to-read/2504/9

Answer (score 1):

We're often bound by the personal preferences of those who write the tools we use.

Standardisation is a good thing, even if we may not agree with specific standards.